# Partially expand VCF bgz file in Linux

Tags: linux

I have downloaded gnomAD files from - https://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/downloads

This is the bgz file

https://storage.googleapis.com/gnomad-public/release/2.1.1/vcf/genomes/gnomad.genomes.r2.1.1.sites.2.vcf.bgz

When I expand using:

```
zcat gnomad.genomes.r2.1.1.sites.2.vcf.bgz > gnomad.genomes.r2.1.1.sites.2.vcf
```

The output VCF file becomes more than 330GB. I do not have that kind of space available on my laptop.

Is there a way where I can just expand - say 1 GB of the bgz file OR just 100000 rows from the bgz file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've been able to determine, a `bgz` file is compatible with `gzip`, and a `VCF` file is a plain text file.  Since it's a `gzip` file, and not a `.tar.gz`, the solution doesn't require listing any archive contents, and simplifies things a bit.

This can probably be accomplished in several ways, and I doubt this is the best way, but I've been able to successfully decompress the first 100,000 rows into a file using the following code in `python3` (it should also work under earlier versions back to `2.7`):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gzip
ifile = gzip.GzipFile("gnomad.genomes.r2.1.1.sites.2.vcf.bgz")
ofile = open("truncated.vcf", "wb")
LINES_TO_EXTRACT = 100000

for line in range(LINES_TO_EXTRACT):
    ofile.write(ifile.readline())

ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

I tried this on your example file, and the truncated file is about 1.4 GiB.  It took about 1 minute, 40 seconds on a raspberry pi-like computer, so while it's slow, it's not unbearably so.

While this solution is somewhat slow, it's good for your application for the following reasons:

- It minimizes disk and memory usage, which could otherwise be problematic with a large file like this.
- It cuts the file to exactly the given number of lines, which avoids truncating your output file mid-line.
- The three input parameters can be easily parsed from the command line in case you want to make a small CLI utility for parsing other files in this manner.