# Opening a VCF.bgz file in python - edit

Tags: file, zip, gzip, vcf-variant-call-format

I have downloaded some data from gnomad - https://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/downloads.
It comes in the form of VCF.bgz file and I would like to read it as a vcf file.

I found some code here: [Partially expand VCF bgz file in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59454001/partially-expand-vcf-bgz-file-in-linux)
by @rnorris .

```
import gzip
ifile = gzip.GzipFile("gnomad.genomes.r2.1.1.sites.2.vcf.bgz")
ofile = open("truncated.vcf", "wb")
LINES_TO_EXTRACT = 100000

for line in range(LINES_TO_EXTRACT):
    ofile.write(ifile.readline())

ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

I tried it on my data and got:

```
Not a gzipped file (b'TB')
```

Is there any way to fix it? I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

"Not a gzipped file" means it's not a gzipped file. Either it was corrupted, downloaded incorrectly, or isn't a gzip file in the first place. A gzip file starts with `b'\x1f\x8b'`. Not `b'TB'`.

A .bgz file *should* be a gzip file, so you likely did not download what you think you downloaded. How did you download it?

Answer (score 0):

The gnomAD datasets should definitely be valid block-gzipped VCF files. Regardless, I think you might have a better time using [Hail](https://hail.is) (disclaimer: I'm a Hail maintainer).

Hail can read directly out of Google Cloud Storage if you install the GCS connector.

```
curl https://broad.io/install-gcs-connector | bash
```

Then in Python:

```py
import hail as hl

mt = hl.read_matrix_table(
    'gs://gcp-public-data--gnomad/release/2.1.1/ht/exomes/gnomad.exomes.r2.1.1.sites.ht'
)
mt = mt.head(100_000)
sites = mt.collect()
```

Comment: hi, i received an error: `Error summary: UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "gs"`. How can i fix this? thanks

Comment: We’re there any errors when you executed the curl | … bash command? The error message you’re describing means that that installation failed. It should’ve downloaded a JAR file and configured it for use with Spark.